# prove that if $f$ is decreasing and bijective, then $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are strictly decreasing.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have done the first part proving f is strictly decreasing, but it is so confusing to prove the inverse function is also strictly decreasing. This is what I have so far, I am not sure if it's correct or not because of so many inequality signs. Here's my proof.

Let $A, B$ the domain and codomain of f. We need to prove that for any $x, y \in A$ and $u,v \in B$, if $x < y$ and $u < v$, we have $f(x) >  f(y)$ and $f^{-1}(u) > f^{-1}(v)$. Assume $x < y$. Since f is decreasing, we have $f(x) \ge f(y)$. Since $x \neq y$ and f is bijective, $f(x) \neq f(y)$, we must have $f(x) > f(y)$. Next, we need to prove that $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing, so assume $u < v$. set $a = f^{-1}(u)$ and $b = f^{-1}(v)$, so we claim that $a > b$. If not, then $a \ge b$. Since f is decreasing, we have $u = f(a) \ge f(b) = v$. This is a contradiction since by our choice, $u < v$. Hence $f^{-1}$ is decreasing.

I am not sure about the part which is $u = f(a) \ge f(b) = v$ is right or not. Because we have $a > b$, $f^{-1}(u) \ge f^{-1}(v)$ which is $a>b$. Then, we take inverse on both side which becomes to $u \ge v$. Am I understanding the definition of decreasing function right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $B$ as the range of $f$, not codomain. There is also an error in the second part of the proof since $a\ge b$ does not imply $f(a)\ge f(b)$. Anyhow the negation of $a>b$ is $a\le b$ which needs to be proven false.

Suppose $a\color{red}{\le}b$. Then due to the decreasing nature of $f$ we have $u=f(a)\ge f(b)=v$ which is a contradiction. Thus $a>b$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you mentioned that $a \ge b$ does not imply $f(a) \ge f(b)$. Can we assume that $f(a) \ge f(b)$ since f is decreasing function by the definition?

Comment: If $a\ge b$ then due to decreasing nature of $f$ we would have $f(a)\le f(b)$. @so0jong